# What is the first occurence of a sequence of short shots of the same length separated by fade ins/outs?

Tags: film-techniques, editing, first-appearance

This technique is used in several movie trailers to give a feeling of stress, anxiety or urgency. It is also used in several movies (mostly thrillers, action or horror movies), sometimes even before the opening credits.

A typical example would be a sequence showing a terrorized woman running in a forest to escape a killer. The sequence would alternate the following close-ups separated by quick fade ins/outs:

1. The woman's feet running and sometimes tripping
2. The killer's feet walking at a quick pace
3. The woman quickly looking behind her to estimate her chances of escaping the killer
4. The killer holding a big knife covered in blood

What is the first occurence of this technique?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Movie Outline's [Glossary Of Screenwriting Terms &
Filmmaking Definitions](http://www.movieoutline.com/articles/a-glossary-of-screenwriting-terms-and-filmmaking-definitions.html):

> FLASH CUT:
>   An extremely brief shot, sometimes as
>   short as one frame, which is nearly
>   subliminal in effect. Also a series of
>   short staccato shots that create a
>   rhythmic effect.

For example:

> - Splice Trailer #2: More [Flash Cuts](http://www.slashfilm.com/splice-trailer-2-more-flash-cuts-more-creature-glimpses/), More
>     Creature Glimpses
> - The trailer is full of
>     horror-film sound effects and [flash cuts](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2011-12-16/news/ct-met-drew-peterson-movie-20111216_1_tragic-wives-joseph-hosey-sergeant-drew-peterson) to seemingly violent images as a woman looks terrified by a
>     garage door going up and down, before
>     Lowe's Peterson is shown on the other
>     side and utters his sole line: "I'm untouchable, bitch."
> - Writer / Director Rob Zombie
>     s hines brilliance throughout this film,
>     punctuated with horribly bad [flash cuts](http://www.feoamante.com/Movies/GHI/House_Corpses.html) 
>     as if the entire movie was one long
>     d rawn-out MTV video. ...

The first occurence maybe in Lawrence of Arabia (1962):

> All art is subjective, but the edit that
>   occurs in this scene after Jackson Bentley
>   (Arthur Kennedy) fires off his flash
>   powder when photographing T.E.
>   Lawrence (Peter O'Toole) is my favorite
>   "edit" in movie history. Perhaps it's the snap from solemn to a loud crash of
>   horse hooves. Or it could be because it's
>   one of the first ["flash cuts"](http://youtube.com/watch?gl=US&hl=en-GB&client=mv-google&v=DQ-ZHNvSrOw&fulldescription=1) in movie
>   history, but it still gives me goosebumps.

Comment: +1: Excellent answer that gives the real name of the technique, several examples and proposes a first occurence.